# When using mc connector, how can I calculate data storage usage amount in salescloud or marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I'd like to connect a salescloud and marketing cloud by using mc connector. After connecting, I will upload customer's website data into a salescloud first and then, I want to make a syncronized data extension in the marketing cloud by using those data. It means every data extension data should be in the salescloud data storage. As I know, the marketing cloud corporate edition license has 45GB for data extension, but salescloud has only 1GB for data. Also I know that a size of records is only 2KB in the salescloud. If so, should I calculate differently in salescloud and marketing cloud?